# Redis for API calls

Tags: api, redis, key-value-store

Redis is single threaded yet it is fast. Can we use Redis database for API calls as APIs call is concurrent in nature? Is Redis capable of handling multiple API call requests?

Answer (score 7):

Yes, you can use Redis at the database for a system that needs to support multiple concurrent API calls.

When you implement your API calls using whatever framework and language you are interested in using, if your API implementation needs to make a request to Redis, that call will wait on the accept queue for the socket until your request gets processed.

Many large websites use Redis as a database to implement APIs in the manner you suggest.

Comment: Yet requests will be in the queue, and it will take the time to process those request. Hence a user has to wait for a while for the response. Is there any way to solve this problem?

Comment: Your requests to Redis are generally going to be served in under 1 millisecond, which is quite fast relative to other operations that have to be performed as part of the API call.  There are various ways to distributed the request load to make Redis perform even better, but it would be easier to address your performance concerns with a more specific problem statement.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can use.

`Redis` is very very fast. You might want to take a look at their [benchmark](https://redis.io/topics/benchmarks). Moreover, we can scale `Redis` horizontally via clustering and partitioning.

> Partitioning allows scaling the computational power to multiple cores and multiple computers, and the network bandwidth to multiple computers and network adapters.

https://redis.io/topics/partitioning

https://redis.io/topics/cluster-tutorial